# What controls the image quality in IIS based on the following example?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, asp.net, image

I had this question before "[Resize image on the fly make the image lose quality online but locally works nice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713830/resize-image-on-the-fly-make-the-image-lose-quality-online-but-locally-works-nice)"

And what i got now is that it's not a problem of local or online, i ran this resize on the server itself "dedicated server", and i got the same bad quality image, so the problem is in the IIS configurations.

What in iis can make this bad quality image happen?

Comment: Can you post an example of the two images? THe low quality and the high quality? It's much, much easier to tell you what the effects are and then work backwards from there. We can then tell if it's JPG compression levels, the resampling technique (bicubic, nearest neighbour, etc) or something different.

Comment: This is the low quality one: amrelgarhy.com/website2 and the original image before resize: http://amrelgarhy.com/website2/U204.jpg , and i am sure that the problem is not in the resize code, as it's already running fine in different places but not by writing directly to the response.outputstream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing. It is totally not an IIS option at all to resize pictures. THat simple.

I t is either the browser, or your resize code (i.e. the :NET code) that results in a bad algorithm.

IIS just serves teh bytes it is asked to send.